# mSelect Image.setImageURI(ImageUrl) is not showing image in android without showing any error

Tags: android, image-gallery, firebase-storage

I'm trying to fetch image from gallery. But it is not showing though all works without any error.
I'm following this [Tutorial from Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tG6Vqi7Ur9A&index=18&list=PLGCjwl1RrtcTXrWuRTa59RyRmQ4OedWrt) and here is my code:

```
 mSelectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,GALLERY_REQUEST);

        }
    });
```

and this is onActvityResut method

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && requestCode == RESULT_OK){

          Uri imageUri = data.getData();

        CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                .start(this);

    }
    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
            mSelectImage.setImageURI(resultUri);

        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            Exception error = result.getError();
        }
    }

}
```

and this is the [dependency](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) I'm using

```
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+'
```

App runs perfectly without any error but the image doesn't show and as I'm trying to use it with Firebase , So what to do?

Answer (score 1):

your if statement can't ever be true because request code can't be equal to GALLERY_REQUEST and RESULT_OK at the same time

```
if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && requestCode == RESULT_OK){
```

replace it with

```
if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
```